# Join period of time, grouping by id

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have rows with periods of time that intersect for the same user. For example:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    ID_USER    |     START_DATE      |      END_DATE       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:00:00 | 01/01/2018 08:50:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:15:00 | 01/01/2018 08:20:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:45:00 | 01/01/2018 09:55:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 15:45:00 | 01/01/2018 17:00:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 08:45:00 | 01/01/2018 09:50:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 09:15:00 | 01/01/2018 10:00:00 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to avoid it. I would like to join rows in one single column, taking the starting date as the oldest and the ending date as the newest. The result of the above example would be:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    ID_USER    |     START_DATE      |      END_DATE       |
-------------------------------------------------------------
|       1       | 01/01/2018 08:00:00 | 01/01/2018 09:55:00 |
|       1       | 01/01/2018 15:45:00 | 01/01/2018 17:00:00 |
|       2       | 01/01/2018 08:45:00 | 01/01/2018 10:00:00 |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Have you any idea how can I get the solution I want with a SQL sentence in Oracle?

Comment: This kind of problem is not easy to do in SQL -- I'd suggest doing on the front end system if possible.  If you can't do that then you probably need a stored procedure

Comment: FYI here is an write up by @Quassnoi for SQL Server which uses an SP and a Loop https://explainextended.com/2009/06/11/flattening-timespans-sql-server/ -- it is quite old so it might be that modern CTE solutions are better.  Still an enjoyable read.

Answer (score 3):

You have two types of intersection; the first where one period exists entirely within another (e.g. your second row, 08:15-08:20), and the second where one period overlaps the start or end of another.

If you eliminate the first type then you can use lead and lag to peek ahead and behind at what's left; I've added a third data set for further fun:

```
select id_user, start_date, end_date,
  case when start_date <= lag(end_date) over (partition by id_user order by start_date)
       then null
       else start_date
  end as calc_start_date,
  case when end_date >= lead(start_date) over (partition by id_user order by end_date)
       then null
       else end_date
  end as calc_end_date
from your_table t1
where not exists (
    select *
    from your_table t2
    where t2.id_user = t1.id_user
    and t2.start_date <= t1.start_date and t2.end_date >= t1.end_date
    and t2.rowid != t1.rowid
);
```

```
   ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE            CALC_START_DATE     CALC_END_DATE         
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------------------
         1 2018-01-01 08:00:00 2018-01-01 08:50:00 2018-01-01 08:00:00                       
         1 2018-01-01 08:45:00 2018-01-01 09:55:00                     2018-01-01 09:55:00   
         1 2018-01-01 15:45:00 2018-01-01 17:00:00 2018-01-01 15:45:00 2018-01-01 17:00:00   
         2 2018-01-01 08:45:00 2018-01-01 09:50:00 2018-01-01 08:45:00                       
         2 2018-01-01 09:15:00 2018-01-01 10:00:00                     2018-01-01 10:00:00   
         3 2018-01-01 08:00:00 2018-01-01 08:30:00 2018-01-01 08:00:00                       
         3 2018-01-01 08:15:00 2018-01-01 08:45:00                                           
         3 2018-01-01 08:45:00 2018-01-01 09:15:00                                           
         3 2018-01-01 09:00:00 2018-01-01 09:30:00                     2018-01-01 09:30:00
```

The `not exists` clause removed the first type.

You can then collapse what is left, firstly by eliminating the rows that overlapped both ends (in my extra rows for ID 3), which have both the lead and lag values as null; and then using lead and lag again to replace the remaining nulls with their adjacent rows' values:

```
select distinct id_user,
  case when calc_start_date is null
       then lag(calc_start_date) over (partition by id_user order by start_date)
       else calc_start_date
  end as start_date,
  case when calc_end_date is null
       then lead(calc_end_date) over (partition by id_user order by end_date)
       else calc_end_date
  end as end_date
from (
  select id_user, start_date, end_date,
    case when start_date <= lag(end_date) over (partition by id_user order by start_date)
         then null
         else start_date
    end as calc_start_date,
    case when end_date >= lead(start_date) over (partition by id_user order by end_date)
         then null
         else end_date
   end as calc_end_date
  from your_table t1
  where not exists (
      select *
      from your_table t2
      where t2.id_user = t1.id_user
      and t2.start_date <= t1.start_date and t2.end_date >= t1.end_date
      and t2.rowid != t1.rowid
  )
)
where calc_start_date is not null
or calc_end_date is not null
order by id_user, start_date, end_date;
```

```
   ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE           
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 2018-01-01 08:00:00 2018-01-01 09:55:00
         1 2018-01-01 15:45:00 2018-01-01 17:00:00
         2 2018-01-01 08:45:00 2018-01-01 10:00:00
         3 2018-01-01 08:00:00 2018-01-01 09:30:00
```

It wouldn't entirely surprise me if there are edge cases I haven't considered and which cause problems, but hopefully will be a starting point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There are four steps required to get the result, represented with three subqueries and one main query:

**1) increase END_DATE to the maximum thus far**

This is required, as your `END_DATE` is not ordered, e.g. the first record intersects with the third record, but the second record doen't intersect with the third one.

```
   ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE          
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 01.01.2018 08:00:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00 
         1 01.01.2018 08:15:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00 
         1 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:55:00 
         1 01.01.2018 15:45:00 01.01.2018 17:00:00 
         2 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:50:00 
         2 01.01.2018 09:15:00 01.01.2018 10:00:00
```

**2) Define a new group for each non-overlapping chunk**

Technically for the first record (per USER_ID) and for each record that doesn't overlap with ist predecessor - assign a new group_id (`GRP`)

```
    ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE                   GRP
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
         1 01.01.2018 08:00:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00          1 
         1 01.01.2018 08:15:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00            
         1 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:55:00            
         1 01.01.2018 15:45:00 01.01.2018 17:00:00          4 
         2 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:50:00          1 
         2 01.01.2018 09:15:00 01.01.2018 10:00:00
```

**3) Fill the Groups**

Fill the `NULL`s with the last group Id assigned to enable GROUP BY.

```
   ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE                  GRP2
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
         1 01.01.2018 08:00:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00          1 
         1 01.01.2018 08:15:00 01.01.2018 08:50:00          1 
         1 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:55:00          1 
         1 01.01.2018 15:45:00 01.01.2018 17:00:00          4 
         2 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 09:50:00          1 
         2 01.01.2018 09:15:00 01.01.2018 10:00:00          1
```

**4) GROUP BY**

The rest is simple, the dates are MIN and MAX within the group. You group on the kay (`ID_USER`) **and** teh `GRP`.

```
   ID_USER START_DATE          END_DATE          
---------- ------------------- -------------------
         1 01.01.2018 08:00:00 01.01.2018 09:55:00 
         1 01.01.2018 15:45:00 01.01.2018 17:00:00 
         2 01.01.2018 08:45:00 01.01.2018 10:00:00
```

The query

```
with myt1 as (
select ID_USER, START_DATE, 
max(END_DATE) over (partition by ID_USER order by START_DATE) END_DATE
from my_table),
myt2 as (
select ID_USER,START_DATE, END_DATE,
case when (nvl(lag(END_DATE) over (partition by ID_USER order by START_DATE),START_DATE-1) < START_DATE ) then 
     row_number() over (partition by ID_USER order by START_DATE) end grp
from myt1 
), 
myt3 as (
select ID_USER,START_DATE, END_DATE,
last_value(grp ignore nulls) over (partition by ID_USER order by START_DATE) as grp2
from myt2
),
select
ID_USER, 
min(START_DATE) START_DATE, 
max(END_DATE) END_DATE
from myt3
group by ID_USER, GRP2
order by 1,2;
```

The data

```
create table my_table as 
select      1 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 08:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 08:50:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual union all
select      1 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 08:15:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 08:20:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual union all
select      1 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 08:45:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 09:55:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual union all
select      1 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 15:45:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 17:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual union all
select      2 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 08:45:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 09:50:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual union all
select      2 ID_USER,   to_date('01/01/2018 09:15:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') START_DATE, to_date('01/01/2018 10:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') END_DATE from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the MIN/MAX function:

```
SELECT MIN(aggregate_expression),MAX(aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
GROUP BY ID;
```

Reference:
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/min.php

Comment: This does not work -- note there are two rows in the result with ID_USER of 1.  This means there was a "hole" in the results.

Comment: Your criteria for this is a bit complicated though. What is it that makes the 2nd row for the ID_USER of 1 appear twice? The bit "I would like to join rows in one single column". You want a single row. That's what I showed you.

Comment: "periods of time that intersect" - the first three rows for ID 1 intersect/overlap so they need to 'collapse' into the overall start/end that covers all of them. The fourth row for ID 1 doesn't overlap the first three, so that appears separately. (I think, that's how I read it and understood the expected results anyway!)

Comment: @kowieleroux -- it is not my criteria -- I'm not the original poster (OP).  This is a standard problem and thus not so complex in my opinion.  Merging date ranges is a question you will see here time and time again.  Welcome to the site -- I hope you enjoy it.